# Let $A$ and $B$ be square matrices of the same size such that $AB = BA$ and $A$ is nilpotent. Show that $AB$ is nilpotent.

Tags: matrices, nilpotence

A square matrix $A$ is called nilpotent is $A^k=0$ for some positive integer $k$.

Let $A$ and $B$ be square matrices of the same size such that $AB = BA$ and $A$ is nilpotent. Show that $AB$ is nilpotent.

Following that is $AB$ not equal to $BA$ in part (b), must $AB$ be nilpotent?

I don't get how to prove this. Since $A$ can represent any matrix. I have no idea how to show it.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: if $AB=BA$ then
$$(AB)^k=A^kB^k\ .$$

For the second part (with $AB\ne BA$) try
$$A=\pmatrix{1&-1\cr1&-1\cr}\ ,\quad B=\pmatrix{4&3\cr2&1\cr}\ .$$

Answer (score 1):

Let A be nilpotent and let $k$ be the positive integer such that $A^k=0$. Since $AB=BA$, then:

$$(AB)^k=\underbrace{(AB)(AB)\cdots(AB)}_{k\text{ times}}=(AB)(BA)(AB)\cdots(AB)=ABBA(AB)\cdots(AB)= B^kA^k=A^kB^k.$$

We obtained the product above by rearranging the parentheses and using commutativity repeatedly.Since $A^k=0$, $(AB)^k=A^kB^k=0B=0$ But then this means for $k$, $(AB)^k=0$ and that means $AB$ is nilpotent. QED.

The reason it doesn't work if the matrices don't commute is because the product $(AB)^k$ cannot be rearranged into separate products of $A$ and $B$ to yield $A^kB^k$. To see this, expand the product and see if you can rearrange it without the commutativity. You can't.

Of course, you can also disprove it via a specific counterexample like David does, but that doesn't tell you **why** it fails in general.

Comment: I dont think *that* is why it does not work. How do you know there is no other clever way of doing it without rearranging the factors?

Answer (score 0):

We have $A^k = 0$ for some $k \in \Bbb N$. Look at:

\begin{align*}
(AB)^k ={}& \underbrace{(AB)(AB)\cdots(AB)}_{k\text{ times}} = A(BA)(BA)\cdots(BA)B = A(AB)(AB)\cdots(AB)B ={} \\
{}={}& A^2(BA)(BA)\cdots B^2 = \dots = A^kB^k = 0B^k = 0.
\end{align*}

In fact, you can just show by induction that $AB = BA \Rightarrow (AB)^n = A^nB^n$, $\forall$ $n \in \mathbb N$, and proceed directly.

Comment: Induction seems like overkill in this problem,but it's certainly a valid way to attack it.

Comment: The induction is for a special statement, which you also happen to use.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234, induction is the way to properly do what you wrote using ellipses.